# Automating build task with unique ids

Tags: visual-studio-code, embedded

I've written some embedded code (using VS-Code as my IDE) that is ready for deployment to many different devices.

The code contains a file `config.h` that defines a unique `device_id` that needs to change for each device.

I have a file `unique_ids.csv` that contains all of the unique ids that I need to use.

VS-Code can automatically build my project and creates a file called `project_name.bin`.

How can I set up a script that automatically takes the uniqe ids from my CSV file and builds a specific `device_id.bin` file for each one?

I suspect this may require utilizing Visual Studio Tasks in some way. Here is my current `tasks.json`:

#### tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "name": "make",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "cpp",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}/mbed-os"],
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "severity": 4,
            "message": 5
        }
    },
    "args": ["-j"],
    "linux": {
        "command": "make"
    },
    "osx": {
        "command": "make"
    },
    "windows": {
        "command": "make.exe"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking of an alternative approach, I might not be answering directly.

If you are using the csv for release and not for debug, why would you build the release inside VS? 
I would rather build my debug inside VS and build my different releases using command line with a batch script.

Something like this batch pseudo code

```
set id_list=unique_ids.csv
set id=
for %%a in (%id_list%) do (
    set "id=%%~na"
    replace in config.h device_id by device_%id%
    make your_project
)
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, skipping VS and using a batch script is definitely the better way to go here. I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands) useful after researching more.